# wc_update_order_item not saving correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to update the Item Name in the `wp_woocommerce_order_items` table and found the function `wc_update_order_item` to do the trick.

I want it to change to a randomly picked product. They main thing here is I already know the `order_item_id` that I want to change.

Here's my code:

```
    $order_item_id = array(1,2,3);
    $num = 3;
    $ctr = 0;

    $products = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => $num,
       'orderby'        => 'rand',
    ));

    if ( $products->have_posts() ): while ( $products->have_posts() ): $products->the_post();

        wc_update_order_item($order_item_id[$ctr], array('order_item_name' => $products->post->post_title));

        $ctr++;

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
```

The `wc_update_order_item()` is where it is supposed to update the order item name. It does update the order_item_name but not with the current $products->post->post_title value. It updates with with a random product title.

How do I know the title being saved is different from the current post_title inside the loop? If I `echo $products->post->post_title` inside the loop, it displays the current product name, as it should, but the updated `order_item_name` has a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following that will get the related product IDs corresponding to the Order items, to exclude them from the WP_Query, avoiding having the same product names:

```
$order_item_ids = array(1,2,3);
$num = 3;
$ctr = 0;

$exluded_ids = array();

// Loop through the Order items Ids
foreach ( $order_item_ids as $item_id ) {
    // Get the order ID from the order Item ID
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id( $item_id );

    // Get the WC_Order object instance
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get the WC_Order_Item_Product object instance
    $item = $order->get_item( $item_id );

    // Products IDs to be excluded from the WP_Query (array)
    $exluded_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
}

$products = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'      => 'product',
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => $num,
   'orderby'        => 'rand',
   'post__not_in'   => $exluded_ids,
));

if ( $products->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $products->have_posts() ): $products->the_post();
        wc_update_order_item($order_item_id[$ctr], array('order_item_name' => $products->post->post_title));
        $ctr++;

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
```

It should work.

---

Now as we don't know how you get the `$order_item_id` array, it's not possible to know what really happen. It should be better to explain what you are trying to do from the start.

Comment: Thanks. There are actually no duplicate product names being generated. It's just that a different value of `$products->post->post_title` is being saved than the one that is in the loop. I removed the `'orderby'        => 'rand',` in the query and the problems went away. I do need the products to be random though so it's not the same product every time.

Comment: @badboy But your actual code is not testable as it doesn't allow to reproduce your issue. You should try to give the context in your question as we really don't catch the story. `$order_item_id = array(1,2,3);` doesn't help and `$ctr = 0;`  is set to nothing.